# How to shrink the size of the Page Header of an RDLC report when on the first page?

Tags: report, rdlc

I am building an RDLC report. Inside the Page Header I putted a Rectangle with text boxes that will show some data **on the top of each page except the firs one.**
The data (from the Rectangle and the Rectangle itself) shown on the first page I am hiding by using an expression like this: **=Globals!PageNumber = 1** (or using the Page Header Properties - "Print on first page" check box).

When exported the report to PDF the result was as I expected but there is a blank space with the size of the Rectangle.

The goal is:

1. Based on the Page Number the data from Rectangle to be shown always on the top of the 2nd, 3rd,... etc. pages (this was achieved).

**2. To remove that blank space on the first page in order the data inside the body to start from the the top of the first page.**

How I can achieve that, is it possible or not?

Thanks

Comment: Old question but anyway, I don't think you can for RDLC report.